# Unknown "server" variable from nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm deploying containerized nginx server onto AWS. However, when I try to access it I get "Unable to connect" error from the browser. Log file is giving me error: `nginx: [emerg] unknown "server" variable`

This is my prod.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://users:5000;
        proxy_redirect      default;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server-name;
    }
}
```

this is in Dockerfile-prod file:

```
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY /prod.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

compose-prod.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  users:
    build:
    context: ./services/users
    dockerfile: Dockerfile-prod
  expose:
    - '5000'
  environment:
    - FLASK_ENV=production
    - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.ProductionConfig
    - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_prod
    - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_test
  depends_on:
    - users-db

users-db:
  build:
    context: ./services/users/project/db
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  expose:
    - '5432'
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

nginx:
  build:
    context: ./services/nginx
    dockerfile: Dockerfile-prod
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 80:80
  depends_on:
    - users
```

Why is it giving me this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$server_name` with underscore instead of `$server-name` http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name

Comment: Can't believe I was stuck on this underscore for 5 days !

Comment: I still can't connect to the app though. Everything is in green now (thanks to you), but browser throws "Unable to connect".